# How to implement Testing & Training data without train_test_split?

Tags: python, regression

I have training and testing data in two separate files and I'm trying to implement a regression on the training data to fit a model onto the testing data. The training data has the y and x variables, the testing data only has the x variables. I've searched for hours on how to do supervised ML on python but every example I've come across involves train_test_split, which isn't useful for me given the data is already split and given the test data doesn't include the y variable. I've already tried implementing train_test_split anyways for good measure but had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular, it is useful to provide code samples of your own attempt(s) to solve the problem.

Comment: Would you please post or link to the training data?

Comment: Please provide more information about data file type (.txt, .csv, etc) & structure of the data. Simple copy paste or screenshot will help.